# $scope not displaying data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The `$scope` data is not displaying on the page.
I have 2 views that are using the same controller.

I have this view, and I'm clicking the edit issue button

```
<div class="container" data-ng-init="adminInit()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h1>Issues Admin</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="add-issue">
          Add Issue
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3>Current Issues</h3>
      <ul ng-repeat="issue in issues">
        <li>
          <strong>{{issue.title}}</strong> - Current Status:
          <strong>{{issue.status}}</strong>
          <div ng-hide="true" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-click="editIssue(issue._id)"></div>
          <div class="btn btn-xs btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-click="editIssue(issue._id)"></div>
          <div class="btn btn-xs btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deleteIssue(issue._id)"></div>
        </li>
        <ul>
          <li>{{issue.description}}</li>
          <li>Issue Logged at: {{issue.timestamp | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this in my controller

```
$scope.editIssue = function(id) {
  $state.go('edit-issue');

  $http.get(Configuration.API + 'api/issue/' + id)
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.issueToEdit = response.data;
      console.log($scope.issueToEdit);
    });
};
```

then the edit-issue view

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h1>Edit Issue</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form name="frm" ng-submit="updateIssue()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="editIssueTitle">Issue Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="editIssueTitle" id="editIssueTitle" class="form-control" ng-model="issueToEdit.title" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="editIssueDesc">Issue Description</label>
          <textarea name="editIssueDesc" id="editIssueDesc" class="form-control"  cols="60" rows="16" ng-model="issueToEdit.description" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="editIssueStatus">Issue Status</label>
          <select name="editIssueStatus" id="editIssueStatus" class="form-control" ng-model="issueToEdit.status" required>
            <option value="Identified">Identified</option>
            <option value="Investigating">Investigating</option>
            <option value="Monitoring">Monitoring</option>
            <option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="frm.$invalid">Go</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the `issueToEdit` data is never displayed 
The console.log line displays the right data

```
{
"_id": "58135b6e3987b8a90c4fc15b"
"title": "Test"
"description": "Testset"
"timestamp": "2016-10-28T14:06:38.284Z"
"status": "Monitoring"
"__v": 0
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: Let me clarify a little, when I land on the edit-issue page, I want the `issueToEdit` data to displayed in the form so that I can then update the info and then save it.

EDIT2: Here is my full controller and app.js

```
app.controller('issuesController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$interval', 'auth', 'Configuration', function($scope, $http, $state, $interval, auth, Configuration) {

    $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;

    $scope.getIssues = function() {
        console.log('retrieving issues');
        $http.get(Configuration.API + 'api/issue')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.issues = data;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

    $scope.addIssue = function() {
        var nIssue = {
            'title': $scope.newissue.title,
            'description': $scope.newissue.description,
            'timestamp': new Date(),
            'status': $scope.newissue.status
        }

        $http.post(Configuration.API + 'api/issue', nIssue)
            .success(function(data) {
                $state.go('admin');
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

    $scope.editIssue = function(id) {
      $state.go('edit-issue');

      $http.get(Configuration.API + 'api/issue/' + id)
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
          $scope.issueToEdit = response.data;
          console.log($scope.issueToEdit);
        });
    };

    $scope.updateIssue = function() {
      //ToDo add this logic
    };

    $scope.deleteIssue = function(id) {
        $http.delete(Configuration.API + 'api/issue/' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.issues = data;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

    $scope.adminInit = function() {
        $scope.getIssues();
        $interval($scope.getIssues, 60000);
    };

    $scope.issueInit = function() {
        $scope.getIssues();
        $interval($scope.getIssues, 60000);

        $(".devInfo").text(navigator.userAgent);
        $(".flashVersion").text(FlashDetect.raw);
    };
}]);
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('supportWebsite', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/articles');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/pages/issues/index.html',
            controller: 'issuesController'
        })
        .state('admin', {
            url: '/admin',
            templateUrl: '/pages/issues/admin/index.html',
            controller: 'issuesController',
            onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth) {
                if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            }]
        })
        .state('add-issue', {
            url: '/admin/add-issue',
            templateUrl: '/pages/issues/admin/add.html',
            controller: 'issuesController',
            onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth) {
                if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            }]
        })
        .state('edit-issue', {
            url: '/admin/edit-issue',
            templateUrl: '/pages/issues/admin/edit.html',
            controller: 'issuesController',
            onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth) {
                if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            }]
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: The problem is, that when you are changing the state, your controller is loaded again. In this moment you are losing your data. You should first change the state, and then load the data. Or you switch the views with ng-hide instead of the state.

Comment: Whats your controller code? It will help to see what are you assigning to the scope

Comment: Is that not what I am doing? $state.go, then the http call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method tells the $state service to go to another state. That will replace the view by the view associated with the new state, create a new $scope, and a new controller instance using this new $scope.

So whatever you put in the $scope of the current controller is irrelevant and useless: the other state uses another $scope and another controller.

You need to pass the ID of the issue to edit as a parameter of the new state. And the controller of this new state (or one of its resolve functions) should use that ID to get the issue to edit.

If you want to stay on the same view, using the same controller and the same scope, then you shouldn't navigate to another state.

Comment: I edited my question to include the full controller.  I am using 1 controller.  I was thinking that all logic pertaining to `issues` should be in 1 place.  Easy to find and see whats going on.  Would that change the situation?

Comment: Yes. Basically, 1 controller = 1 view. Using a single controller for several views will only make things more complex and bloated than necessary. If you need common logic between controllers, use a shared service.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.  Time to refactor.  Again.